# Ошибка при запуске проекта из Bash консоли с использованием .jar библиотеки

Tags: java, bash, jar

Здравствуйте возникла такая проблема, после компиляции проекта через Bash консоль при попытке запустить программу из той же консоли возникает такая ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура моего проекта выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Main.java выглядит так:

```
 package com.my;

 import com.my.cla.Test;

 public class Main
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test test= new Test();
        test.method();
    }
 }
```

Test.java выглядит вот так:

```
package com.my.cla;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

public class Test
{
    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        System.out.println(StringUtils.upperCase("Hello World!"));
    }
}
```

Команды из Bash консоли которые я использовал для компиляции проекта и его запуска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста где я мог допустить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как git bash всего лишь оболочка, которая запускается на Windows, разделителем в пути будет точка с запятой `;`, а не двоеточие `:`. Также может понадобиться взять classpath в кавычки:

```
hp1@hp MINGW64 /c/temp
$ java -cp "build/classes;libs/commons-lang3-3.11.jar" com.my.Main
Hello world
HELLO WORLD!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Об этом разделителе указано в подсказке JVM:

```
$ java
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
...
 where options include:

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    --class-path <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```